# How many homomorphisms are there from the graph Cycle 5 to the Peterson Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, cardinals

I’m struggling to work out how many there are. Currently I know there’s 12 unique cycle 5s in the Peterson graph, so by rotation and flip rotation there’s 10 different possibilities. Does this mean there are 120 homomorphisms?

Comment: Yeah, you also have to take advantage of the fact that if 
$$
f:\,C_5\to H
$$
is a graph homomorphism and $f$ is surjective, then $H$ is a cycle of length $\leq5$. In addition, we must take into account that the Petersen graph has no cycles of length less than $5$.

Comment: When you say it’s surjective, are you referencing edge-Surjection?

Comment: I was referring to vertex surjectivity. 
But specifically in this case it didn't matter.